# Is there a reliable Hangul online transliteration service using Japanese kana?

Tags: hangul, transliteration

This is my first question asked on this particular stack exchange site, I believe. I used to be a student of Japanology and I had growing interest in Korean language thanks gaming culture in Korea, particularly League of Legends and Korean teams hegemony.

I'm trying to learn Korean language as of right now, using various books I was able to gather through recommendations. One particular thing that seems to be a hurdle for me when it comes to learning Korean seems to me to be the transliteration of Korean language.

As I have history with learning a foreign Asian language, which seems to have some things in common with Korean, and it'd be much more comfortable for me to learn Korean language and its transliteration using Japanese script.

I know this doesn't seem to be a common thing to ask, nor one that every single person may have an answer to, but it'd be very much appreciated if anyone provided me with any recommended sources! Have a good one, everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I don't know if there's a Hangul-to-kana transliteration service, but I can tell you that learning Korean via Japanese script is a really, really bad idea.

Despite similar grammars, these two languages have very different sound system, so the sound of almost all Korean words will be distorted if written in Kana, and vice versa.  For example, Korean has three dental stops (ㄷ/ㄸ/ㅌ) which is usually Latinized as d/tt/t.  Japanese has two (let's say d/t): but neither matches any of the three Korean sounds well!

In fact, Koreans would perceive both Japanese /d/ and /t/ as Korean /d/ (ㄷ), when it is at the start of a word.  So if you take any Korean word that starts with ㄸ/ㅌ and write it in Kana, and read the characters in the same way a Japanese speaker would, a Korean won't perceive it as the same Korean word.

Just imagine learning English using Japanese script.  yuu uddo bii raaningu tuu supiiku raiku jisu.  (Apologies if I messed up transliteration: I actually don't know Japanese. -_-)

Answer (score 1):

I second the other answer, but if you really want something like this, the Korean wikipedia entry on [Hiragana](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%9E%88%EB%9D%BC%EA%B0%80%EB%82%98) or [Katakana](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B0%80%ED%83%80%EC%B9%B4%EB%82%98) has a table that you can refer to.

Of course, this is a mapping from Korean to Japanese while you're looking for the opposite, and kana are generally unable to accurately capture the sound of more complex hangul. Be especially wary of following those tables too closely, as you may end up speaking Korean with a Japanese accent.